# comment like facebook script

Tags: php

I already have an script where it will allow a user whom is logged in to comment on other users. One field for the usercommenting "men_id" and another field for the user being commented on commented_men_id. Well I save it in a comment table and to pull it I make a while I make a select to get the comment of men_id while getting the comment I do another while loop inside the while loop to get the user name and id to return it in the comment. Now the next step is to let other user to comment on top of the comment that is already there. I was wondering if I have to make another table or just create another table to get the comments on another comments. I was also wondering in terms of the php script will I have to create another while loop inside the second while loop to pull the subcomments?

So far I have the next structure

```
$sql1 = "SELECT id, mem_id, commented_id, comment 
         FROM comments 
         WHERE commented_id = '$id'";

while($row=msql_fetch_array($sql)) {
  $id_coment = $row['id'];
  $mem_id = $row['mem_id'];
  $comment = $row['comment'];

  $sql_member_data = msql_query("SELECT id, member_name FROM users WHERE id ='$id_coment'");

  while($row2=msql_fetchj_array($sql_member_data)) {
    $user_id =$row2['id'];
    $user_name =$row2['member_name'];

    echo '<div>'.$user_name.'</div>';

    echo '<div>'.$comment.'</div>';
  }
}
```

I advise might not be the best code but it is posting the comment, Now how can I get a comment within the comment generated by this script.

Thank you guys.

Comment: let's try to indent better and we can talk

Comment: If you really want a facebook-like comment system, you can also use facebook: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/

Comment: just letting you know I changed the 2nd while statement to assign to `$row2` instead of `$row`.  I also changed the first div content from `$memeber_name` to `$member_name`, although I'm suspecting you want `$user_name` there instead.  I'm not very familiar with PHP, but I believe there are a few more syntactical problems in that code.

Comment: Did you ever try to run this code? It is *full* of syntax errors...

Comment: you are right oliver it is $user_name instead. @thiefmaster this is just a guide. I think I should try to create a sub_comment_id and then with an integer of 11 and a while loop inside the and display the sub_comment associated to that id.,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you truly want a something like Facebook's commenting system, you are going to have to do a lot more than that. I made my own little system and it's nicely styled with some really awesome jQuery effects.

Here's what you are going to need

- Section to get all your comments (which you have -- check for syntax errors)
- Form and script to post your comments

And you will probally need to use jQuery and AJAX for the commenting and some more jQuery to auto-refresh like facebook does.

That's my take on it. No one else hate on me for this, just trying to give some input on it.

```
<?php

// Connect to database here

// Search and start loop to get all comments
$sql_comments = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE type='main'"); 
while($rows_comment=mysql_fetch_array($sql_comments)){

// Get comment information
$main_comment_id = "".$rows_comment['id']."";
$main_comment_mem_id = "".$rows_comment['mem_id']."";
$main_commented_id = "".$rows_comment['commented_id']."";
$main_comment = "".$rows_comment['comment']."";

// Get user information
$sql_member_data = msql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id ='$main_comment_mem_id'");
while($row2=msql_fetchj_array($sql_member_data)) {
$user_id = "".$row2['id']."";
$user_name = "".$row2['member_name']."";
}

// Display comment
echo "<b>$user_name</b><br>$main_comment";

// Search for any sub-comments
$sql_subcomments = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE sub_commented_id='$main_comment_id' AND type='sub'";
while($row_subcomment=msql_fetchj_array($sql_subcomments)) {

// Get sub comment information
$subcomment_id = "".$row_subcomment['id']."";
$sucomment_mem_id = "".$row_subcomment['mem_id']."";
$subcomment_comment = "".$row_subcomment['comment']."";

// Get sub commenter information
$sql_member_data_sub = msql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id ='$subcomment_mem_id'");
    while($row2_sub=msql_fetchj_array($sql_member_data_sub)) {
        $user_id_sub = "".$row2_sub['id']."";
        $user_name_sub = "".$row2_sub['member_name']."";
    }

    // Echo sub comment
    echo "<div style='margin-left: 20px;'><b>$user_name_sub</b><br>$subcomment_comment</div>";

}

}

?>
```

Comment: great comment and very helpful. I have a question can I be jquery and AJAX on the php script I have or I finish building?

Comment: You can put it in the PHP file. Basically what it does is it won't reload the page when you submit your form. It will then post data to a external PHP file. If successful, you can make your comment have a nice little slideUp, fadeIn, toggle, or whatever you want. That's what's kinda cool about jQuery!

Comment: That jquery and ajax is killing me right now I just focus on the php

Comment: right now I just focus on the displaying a comment below a coment I was thinking on putting a while inside the while loop that display the comments with a condition WHERE commented_id =   $id_coment

Comment: That's good for a start! jQuery isn't really that hard after you can get through it. It gets to be fun and you want to start animating everything. ha.

Comment: man that great when you don't have to refresh the whole page to see the updates

Comment: it is nice. i haven't actually done that yet because all the websites i made are very low-traffic and it would be pointless.

Comment: can you give a hint please on where I should wrap another while loop to get the comments related to that the original comment. should I wrap it around the users query or the comment query? it would be like a $sql = "select id, mem_id, commented_id,sub_commen_id, comment FROM comments WHERE sub_commented_id = id

Comment: ok yes sometimes it can turn confusing when another is doing. I am eager to see thanks.

Comment: Sorry it took so long. I didn't test it, so there could be some errors. Note: I added a `type` to the table to tell whether it's a sub comment or main comment. This is easier with searching for it. Another snippet of info, you don't need to write out all your columns in your sql. Simply replace it all with `*` like I did in my example. Test it and tell me what you get.

Comment: Great idea on the type field... I will have to go ahead and create one

Comment: @phpnerd I have added a p tag and a tags in the display for main comment so that if the user click on the comment a comment link then it will display or a form will appear like with the help of jquery and ajax for the user to subcomment. Where does the href will link the user?

Comment: `<a href='#'>comment</a>` and the rest will be handled by jQuery.